# Confirmation of Proof: $\forall a,b \in\mathbb{R}, \ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a}{b^n} = \frac{ab}{b-1}\Leftrightarrow \frac b2\in(1, a].$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification, summation, proof-writing

I have created the following conjecture:

> > $$\forall a,b \in\mathbb{R}, \ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a}{b^n} = \frac{ab}{b-1}\Leftrightarrow \frac b2\in(1, a].$$

However, I cannot prove this.

---

**My Attempt:**

I applied the ratio test to see whether or not the sum converges.

Let $r_n = \dfrac{a}{b^n}$ then I evaluated the following limit:

$$L = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{r_{n+1}}{r_n} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(r_{n+1}\cdot\frac{1}{r_n}\right) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{a}{b^n}\cdot\frac{b^{n+1}}{a}\right) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{b^{n+1}}{b^n} = \lim_{n\to\infty}b = b.$$

I obviously did something wrong; rather, I feel I need to do something like

> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a}{b^n} = a\cdot\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{b^n} = a\cdot 0 = 0,\tag*{$\because b > 1$}$$

but I am not sure. I mean, if $L = 0$, then $L < 1$ and therefore the series is absolutely convergent.

---

Could somebody please help me?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you just have $b \in (1,a]$ that tells us that $1/b < 1$ which then enables us to say $a \sum_{n=0}^\infty 1/b^n = a(\frac{b}{b-1})$ via the geometric series, correct?

Comment: @TrostAft I guess so. I just began learning the ratio test, and I wanted to apply it to some random sums I came up with to get a feel for it. I then observed something and that became my conjecture.

Comment: Well, how else do we learn if not trying new things? Also you can probably weaken your constraint of $b/2 \in (1,a]$ to $b \in (1,a]$.

Comment: @TrostAft yes, I see now. If $b/2 \in (1, a]$ then of course $b\in(2, 2a]\Rightarrow b\in(1, 2a]$. This means that $b > 1$ and that means that $|1/b| < 1$, so it converges. No ratio test necessary. And I now also know that $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{x^n} = \frac{1}{1-x^{-1}}.$$ Thank you very much :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{a}{b^n}$ is a geometric series, hence it converges if and only if $|\frac{1}{b}|<1$

If you evaluate the sum you get $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{a}{b^n}=a\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{b}}=\frac{ab}{b-1}$

Your ratio test gives $\frac{1}{b}$ rather than $b$ - this says that the series converges for $|\frac{1}{b}|<1$

Comment: I never knew of the geometric series formula. Thank you for telling me :D